My enemy sent me this puzzle!
My lifelong nemesis unexpectedly sent me a box of chocolates, accompanied with this love note. I don't know what's going on! Maybe I have misread our entire relationship? I haven't opened the chocolates yet. Do you think I should try them?

How do I love ❤️ thee? Let me count the ways.
I love thee like my favourite song, the fourth on 808,
   like a winning diagonal from a 45-degree angle,
   and like Bilbo's years at his party.
I love thee like my man Philippe Diallo, who heads this soccer group,
   and like the company that made my favourite game, Halo 4.
I love thee like the mighty bomber, the Rockwell Lancer, the one from the 80s,
   and like the plane named "Schwalbe" from WWII.
Yours, [enemy]. 



 I don’t think that would be a good idea.

Why?

 Let’s look at the clues you have: the fourth song from this album,  in tic tac toe XXX diagonally, Bilbo Baggins’ age was 111 in the his birthday party, this soccer group, this company, this 80s bomber and this German WW2 Plane

Next

 from each of the clues, we are to extract a triple-charactered alphanumerical string which we then have to arrange into a 3x7 grid like so:

 UUU
 +++
 111
 FFF
 343
 B1B
 262

Then

 Notice that by reading the columns downwards left to right you can convert these into unicode and by doing so you get: U+1F3B2 U+1F416 and U+1F3B2

Finally

 Following the emoji hint from the two emojis littered in the puzzle, convert these into emojis and you get: DIE PIG DIE!


Can you expand your explanation for the second clue? I'm completely oblivious to it

There seems to be a mistake actually in the puzzle to according the op in the PSE chat room

@infinitezero "the winning diagonal" (in tic-tac-toe) is XXX, arranged diagonally. Then, turn that 45 degrees to the side and you see +++.

Missing clue added (line 3). Sorry about that! Don't know how I managed to mess that up.

Or maybe the enemy wants to play craps with a pig. You can never be sure with a rebus.

Maybe the enemy is Sideshow Bob?
